# No Local Variable or Arguments in Xcode 3.2/iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gdb, ios

I've updated a project to Xcode 3.2 and the iOS 4 SDK, and now, I don't get any local variables or arguments in gdb.  I've confirmed that Debug Information Format is (still) set to "DWARF with dSYM File," the compiler is GCC 4.2 (no `LLVM` or Clang), and `GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL` is 0.  Any thoughts about what I might be doing wrong?